# Terminal isn't outputting correct decimal values for double and long double. (C++ on VS CODE)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

This is my numericdatatypes.cpp file:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    int main(){
    
        int f1 = 10.1234567890;
        float f2 = 10.1234567890;
        double f3 = 10.1234567890;
        long double f4 = 10.1234567890;
        cout << f1 << "\n" << f2 << "\n" << f3 << "\n" << f4;
    
        return 0;
    }
```

This is the output I'm getting in the terminal:

```
cd "c:\Users\**REDACTED**\OneDrive\Desktop\**REDACTED**\data types\" ; if ($?) { g++ numericdatatypes.cpp -o numericdatatypes } ; if ($?) { .\numericdatatypes }
10
10.1235
10.1235
10.1235
```

Comment: That looks right. By default, writing floating point values to the console shows six digits. What do you want the output to be?

Comment: @PeteBecker I would like the long double to display the full decimals values (output:  10.1234567890 instead of 10.1235).

Comment: To show floating-point values at higher precision, read about [`std::setprecision`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision).

Comment: @zackaria_asks What does "full decimals values" mean? Note that exactly `10.1234567890` is not a value that any of these types can hold (on usual platforms). Each of them will round to the closest representable value.

Comment: @user17732522 what I meant is that for example which variable would I use in order to output 5.1234567890 exactly in the terminal?

Comment: you should ask yourself how significant are these decimals, you use long double to get a better approximation of the first few decimals, and it all depends how you perform the calculation, maybe you only have 4 significant decimals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using fixed << setprecision();